# WPF: pass my TextBox into my converter with my Property together

Tags: wpf, textbox

So i have this `Converter`:

```
public class ComboboxSelectedIndexToTextBoxBackgroundColor : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int selectedIndex = (int)value;
        if (selectedIndex == 0)
            return "Red";
        else
            return "Green";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My binding object has this Property (implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`):

```
public int ComboboxSelectedIndex
{
    get { return _comboboxSelectedIndex; }
    set
    {
        _comboboxSelectedIndex = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

My `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="False"
         Background="{Binding ComboboxSelectedIndex, Converter={StaticResource ComboboxSelectedIndexToTextBoxBackgroundColor}}"
         Margin="0,0,0,0">
```

So if i want to use `MultiBindingConverter` and along my `ComboboxSelectedIndex` property i want slao to sent my `TextBox` - is it possible ?
How can i do that ?

Comment: I think you don't have to do it

Comment: if you want to change background of TextBlock if comboBox.SelectedIndex == 0 you can easily do it via DataTrigger. Of course, converter is good approach too.

Comment: but from your Q is totally unclear why do you want to pass TextBox into converter

Comment: I would be more inclined to use a Behaviour or Data Trigger for this. Trying to achieve this with a converter, whilst possible, isn't really in the spirit of what converters are for, and make your implementation harder for others to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `Name="txt"` attribute to TextBox and use ElementName in binding. TextBox will become the source of binding and without property Path it will be send to converter itself, not property value.

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MvCvt}" Mode="OneWay">
    <Binding Path="ComboboxSelectedIndex"/>
    <Binding ElementName="txt"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

element can also send itself to binding using `{RelativeSource Self}`

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MvCvt}" Mode="OneWay">
    <Binding Path="ComboboxSelectedIndex"/>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

"McCvt" is a some `IMultiValueConverter` implementation here